# Looping back to input box after error occurs

Tags: vba

Just doing a quick exercise below, an input box that converts inches to cm's.
I want to add to the error handler section so that after the msgbox appears explaining an error has occurred it loops back to the inputbox asking me to add inches to convert to centimeters. Thanks

```
Sub Exercise()

Dim m As Variant
Dim result
Dim ErrM As String

On Error GoTo ErrHandler

m = InputBox("How much in Inches would you like to convert to Centimeters?", "Inches to Centimeters", "Please Type here")
result = m * 2.54

MsgBox "There are " & result & " inches", , "Result"

Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
    MsgBox ("An error occured, please type a number into the input box")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way, please:

```
Sub Exercise()
 Dim m As Variant, result As Double

BackInp:
 m = InputBox("How much in Inches would you like to convert to Centimeters?", "Inches to Centimeters", "Please Type here")
 If Not IsNumeric(m) Then
    MsgBox "An error occurred, please type a numeric value into the input box!", _
           vbInformation, "Need to repeate the input..."
    GoTo BackInp
 End If

 result = m * 2.54

 MsgBox "There are " & result & " inches", , "Result"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for error handling in your specific case. Simply, throw the InputBox in a loop, check if the input is a number (e.g., using `IsNumeric`), and decide whether you should continue or repeat based on that.

Example:

```
Do While True
    m = InputBox("How much in Inches would you like to convert to Centimeters?", _
                 "Inches to Centimeters", "Please Type here")
    If StrPtr(m) = 0 Then
        ' The user canceled the operation.
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf Not IsNumeric(m) Then
        ' The input is not a number.
        MsgBox ("Please type a number into the input box.")
    Else
        ' The input is a number. We continue with the code below.
        Exit Do
    End If
Loop

result = m * 2.54
MsgBox "There are " & result & " inches", , "Result"
```